# Running quicker for Numpy and Pandas( installed via conda) than via pip?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda

I have two Python environments (3.6).

I installed packages in one environment via conda, and in another environment via pip.

Then I found that conda-provided numpy and pandas run quicker than pip version (for most of the scenario).

Just wonder why this happens. Is that because they use different configuration during compilation?

Comment: Most likely it is due to a different BLAS linked to numpy - e.g., see http://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html

Answer (score 8):

Yes, most likely this difference is due to different compilation configurations. Numpy makes use of the low-level fortran libraries [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) and [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK). The numpy that you get from pip is compiled with different implementations of BLAS and LAPACK than the numpy that you get from conda. The latter uses the [MKL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) implementation which is optimized specifically for Intel processors.

You can check the implementation that numpy is using in a particular environment with:

```
import numpy as np
np.show_config()
```

Some comparison benchmarks can be found [here](http://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html) (as already noted by *crisb*).

Comment: Thanks. I think it is exactly the case. I'm doing some heavy linear algebra calculation via numpy.