# How to get a maximally performant NumPy installation from Pip?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, conda

While `conda` does a great job of installing a maximally performant *NumPy*, `pip` leaves me with a 6x performance reduction by comparison.
How can I get `pip` to install *NumPy*, such that it yields the same performance as when installed via `conda`?

Comment: @mozway: the linked dupe explains why there is a performance difference (probably). But I don't see how it answers this question. (The linked question sought an explanation; this question seeks a fix.)

Comment: Well, there's a [MKL version of numpy](https://pypi.org/project/intel-numpy/) available at PyPi.

Comment: @rici fair enough I'll reopen, here is the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197337/running-quicker-for-numpy-and-pandas-installed-via-conda-than-via-pip) for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [intel-numpy](https://pypi.org/project/intel-numpy/) package via pip, in order to get the same performance.
Read more about why this happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197337/running-quicker-for-numpy-and-pandas-installed-via-conda-than-via-pip).

In short, conda version was built with [MKL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library).
And the PyPi numpy package was build using [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) and [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK).

p.s. Also that's the reason why Numpy sucks so much with the famous Ryzen Threadripper by default.
But I must say there was a workaround to make MKL work on AMD processors, but intel fixed and removed this possibility.

Comment: Thanks @Abraham! How about for the new Macs w/ Apple silicon?

Comment: @dbanas Currently I own macbook with Intel processor, so I don't face this issue.
But, there was a discussion on Stackoverflow about installing Numpy with Apple's vecLib, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240506/why-python-native-on-m1-max-is-greatly-slower-than-python-on-old-intel-i5).